# Assign values to Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arrayobject

I am trying to create an array of objects. There are 10 nodes for which I am assigning a 'node_id'. I am also assigning values to other variables in the class. The for loop in 'networkInitialization()' method assigns values to 'node_id' in a sequential manner, but when I try to print it in main method it returns all '9'.

```
import java.util.*;
public class tman {
  static int N = 10;
  static int k = 5;
  static Node nodes[] = new Node[N]; 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    networkInitialization();
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
      System.out.println(nodes[i].node_id);
    }
  }
  public static void networkInitialization(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int next;
    double theta;
    System.out.println("Initializing the network");
    for(int i = 0; i<nodes.length; i++){
      nodes[i] = new Node();
      HashSet<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();
  //Nodeid
      nodes[i].node_id = i;
  //        System.out.println(nodes[i].node_id);
  //Generating 'k' random neighbors list
      for(int j = 0; j<k; j++){
        next = random.nextInt(10);
        while (used.contains(next)) { //while we have already used the number
            next = random.nextInt(N); //generate a new one because it's already used
        }
        used.add(next);
//          System.out.println(next);
        nodes[i].neighbors[j] = next;
      }
//Calculating XCo and YCo
      theta = 3.14/2-(i-1)*3.14/(N-2);
      nodes[i].x_co = Math.cos(theta);
      nodes[i].y_co = Math.sin(theta);
      nodes[i].theta = theta;
//      System.out.println(nodes[0].x_co);
    }
  }
}
class Node{
  static int node_id;
  static double x_co;
  static double y_co;
  static double theta;
  static int k = 30;
  static int neighbors[] = new int[k];
  static Map<Integer, int[]> received_list = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
  int N;

  public static int getNodeId(){
    return node_id;
  }

  public static double getXCo(){
    return x_co;
  }

  public static double getYCo(){
    return y_co;
  }

  public static double getTheta(){
    return theta;
  }

  public static int[] getNeighbors(){
    return neighbors;
  }

  public static Map<Integer, int[]> getReceivedList(){
    return received_list;
  }

  public void setNodeId(int node_id){
    this.node_id = node_id;
  }

  public void setXCo(int x_co){
    this.x_co = x_co;
  }

  public void setYCo(int y_co){
    this.y_co = y_co;
  }

  public void setTheta(double theta){
    this.theta = theta;
  }

  public void setNeighbors(int neighbors[]){
    this.neighbors = neighbors;
  }
}
```

This is the output I am getting in main method.

```
Initializing the network
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

Anyone can help me on this ?

UPDATE :
Looks like I have not understood `static` well enough. Removing all the static in the `networkInitialization()` method worked correctly. Thank you.

Comment: I would have a serious look at your over use of `static`

Comment: Sure, I can remove all those. I am a beginner. But my problem is, this statement - nodes[i].node_id = i; is working when I print values just after it. But when I print it in main method. I am getting all 9's.

Comment: You might find [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil), [Why Static is Bad and How to Avoid It](https://dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid), [Java static methods can be a code smell](http://blog.christianposta.com/testing/java-static-methods-can-be-a-code-smell/), [Java Static methods: Good or evil?](http://rafaelrezend.github.io/post/java-static-methods-good-or-evil), [Static is Evil](http://corfield.org/entry/Static_is_Evil) some useful reading

Comment: Yes, it does that because that variable is static, i.e. there's only 1 of it and each `nodes[i].node_id` refers to the same one. This is probably a duplicate of [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413898)

Comment: I have a personal opinion on the subject of `static`, but like most things, it's a two way door. You need to understand what `static` is actually doing, what it's good for (and what it's bad for) and where it should be used, because, yes, it has it's uses, but in your case, you've abused it without fully understanding how it works. You might want to have a read through [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the knowledge!. I removed all the 'static' in the method and it is working as expected. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the problem is in the use of `static` in the definition of `Node`. If a variable is `static`, it means that it will be the same for every instance of that class. To illustrate this, look at the code below:

```
Node a = new Node();
a.node_id = 1;

Node b = new Node();
b.node_id = 2;
```

If `node_id` is not static, it would behave as you would expect: Java creates a `Node a`, which has a field `node_id` that is set to 1 and then goes on to create another `Node b` which has its own field `node_id` that is naturally different from the `node_id` of node a.

However, if `node_id` is static, all nodes share the same field `node_id`! This means that `Node a` sets the shared `node_id` to one, but `Node b` accesses the same `node_id` and sets it to 2.

In your example, the last time the shared field `node_id` is called is when `i = 9`, so the shared `node_id` has a value of 9, regardless of which Node it is.

You said you were a beginner, so you probably won't use `static` much. However, `static` could be useful if, for example, you want to know how many nodes there are in total. In that case you can have a `static` field that keeps track of the number of nodes. Each time another node is called, you increase that number. Because it is shared, all nodes will know how many total nodes there are. If you want to know more about how to use `static`, see the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).